# Looking for a Design Pattern or Library

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there a specific design pattern I could use to generate a string expression with some nested conditions?

Given:

`Builder.red().and().blue().or(white().and().black()).toString()`

Result should be:

`red and blue or ( white and black )`

Initially I started using the builder pattern (maybe it's not the appropriate one) but I got stuck when I had to generate the nested condition. Ideally the usage should be like in the above snippet (method chaining).

I need that for a java project (version 8) and the generated expression will be used as spring expression language (couldn't find a spring utility class that does that).

Comment: Well if the colors are your model impending am interface, the `and `and `or ` would be methods on the interface, returning the same interface type so it'll allow chaining. You'd basically build a grammar with that model.

Comment: @cisk, do you have closed list of `colours`? Do you want to build `query` similar to this: `Builder.value("red").and().value("blue).or(value("white).and().value("black)).toString()`? Do you want to use builder for creating valid logical query or something more?

Answer (score 1):

I recently solved a similar problem by keeping track of my nested expressions in the builder. While I would prefer the chaining like you suggested, I had to put the nested condition between .open() and .close().

Your code would look like

```
Builder.red().and().blue().or().open()
           .white().and().black()
.close().toString()
```

The open() function adds another builder on the stack (inside the builder) and the close() function pops that builder and adds it to the intermediate pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the nested methods are needed for readability and also for letting the builder add parentheses itself (In this way I minimize the generation of invalid expressions).

Comment: You can mitigate that problem by checking your stack upon calling .toString() and ensure all brackets are closed.

Trying to solve it the way you wrote makes you consistently run into the problem that you will implement both a instance and a class method.

You can achieve
`
    n().red().and().white().or( n().white().and().green() )
`
by creating .n() as a static method creating a new builder a static version of or() taking a builder as an argument, enabling nesting. You can't escape calling n() in that case. Just do import static to allow you to write it this way.